# Finite state machine inputs

Tags: state-machines

if a finite state machine has 5 input signals

```
A, B, C, D, E
```

Does this mean there must be 2⁵ inputs along with the state built into the logic?

Comment: 32 POSSIBLE & BINARY input states exist. All may not be used.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are 32 possible input combinations for each state. But in some states, some of the inputs might be "don't cares", so you won't have to write out all the combinations explicitly, whether you're making a state transition table, a state diagram, or writing HDL code to define the state machine.

Comment: i think that you may have meant to say `No, there are 32 possible input combinations for each state, but in some states, .......`

Comment: @jsotola, \$2^{5}=32\$, doesn't it?

Comment: you are correct .... it's just that the OP is using the word "must" ..... the question reads like a school test question .... those are tricky sometimes